many differents agents in the same source, how is it possible in the logic?
For my model, i have to represent 3 differents agents in the same source and coming at the same time. How is the representation possible. I'd also like to know if it's possible to arrange the agents in parallel on a conveyor
here is like an overview of the process I'm blocked by the representation of the source
It should look a little bit like this

The simplest way would be you ideally using three create blocks, like your overview. You can then set one of the blocks for the arrival distribution, and the other two Sources to generate when called inject. On the source with the distribution, you could then call sourceZellen.inject(); sourceFoam.inject() so all 3 will arrive at the same time.
Then the operation you described on your overview looks like one of the operations where you attach several agents. For example, a Combine where you combine the Zellen and Foam into a prepared foam agent, and then use another combine (or a ResourceAttach, or a PickUp) to combine the prepared/packed foam into the pallet (as I am guessing you can separate the Pallet again at a later stage).
